# selector name doesn't match any elements for standalone component in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-module, angular-standalone-components

I'm trying to use stadalone component but it gives me this error:
`The selector "app-login" did not match any elements`
But the thing is, `<app-login></app-login>` is not written anywhere.
My login component:

```
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
  imports: [FormsModule,CommonModule],
})
export class LoginComponent {
  auth = inject(AuthService);

  title = 'trial';
  email!: string;
  password: string = '';

  onSubmit() {
    this.auth.login(this.email, this.password);
  }
}
```

And main.ts includes this code except imports:

```
bootstrapApplication(LoginComponent)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I was trying to use standalone component. I don't know why does app give an error like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you bootstrap a component, you have to write its selector in the `index.html` file, otherwise it won't work.

```html
<body>
  <app-login />
</body>
```

Comment: Why isn't it documented anywhere :(

Comment: Well that's because it's implicit, but also because it's done by default, you seem to have created the issue yourself this time !